# How can I detect overflows in Jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, overflow

How can I automatically detect all overflow/cut off texts in a Jasper report?

My use case: I have a multi-language report. When some translation is changed, I want to make sure that the next (possibly longer text) is not truncated without having to eyeball every change.

The check should work for all elements, even those which grow. Imagine I have a text box which tries to grow and extends past the page border. Maybe a better description would be: I want to know when the engine adds text to the page which the user can't see, no matter what the reason.

Comment: Try to set property stretch with overflow to true.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Do you need some kind of "flag"? Is it ok to just increase the height of textField in automatic mode (by engine)?

Comment: @FahadAnjum I want to know when the text doesn't fit. I don't want the elements to grow.

Comment: @AlexK I was thinking of a kind of problem report for fields where the text doesn't fit even when it grows as much as possible.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no out-of-box solution. IMHO, it is interesting idea to create library to diagnose such problems. You can get under the hood of JasperReports :)

Comment: I've opened a feature request: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/9071

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround: When text overflows, the JasperReports omits it in the PDF (instead of relying on clipping).

You can use a framwork like [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to fetch the text from the page. In a unit test, you can then check that the full text is visible.

This works well with static texts.

I've created a [gist with some demo code](https://gist.github.com/digulla/641e045016763085e04ea617f4a195df).

Dynamic texts are harder because they can overflow in production. You can use the same approach to check whether the text made it on the page unchanged but it's a bit slow.

A faster solution for single line texts is to use the average char width (The [`PDFont` class](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html) has a method [`getAverageFontWidth()`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html#getAverageFontWidth()) for this).

The average amount of characters which fit into the box is `boxWidth / averageCharWidth`. Compare the string length against this value. If it's less, then you're most likely safe. If it's longer, you can at least log a warning with the string.

After some time, you can collect all those logs and try to figure out a better way to determine what texts fit and which don't.

The ideal solution would be an API which passes the font, style and text to JasperReports and gets the width back.